# Reason of this exception in WCF

Tags: c#, wcf

I am learning WCF and right now I am getting one exception while running the application:
Exception:

> Could not find default endpoint
>   element that references contract
>   'IService1' in the ServiceModel client
>   configuration section. This might be
>   because no configuration file was
>   found for your application, or because
>   no endpoint element matching this
>   contract could be found in the client
>   element.

Service Code:

```
namespace StockService
{
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the class name "Service1" in code, svc and config file together.
    public class Service1 : IService1
    {
        public string GetData(int value)
        {
            return string.Format("You entered: {0}", value);
        }

        public CompositeType GetDataUsingDataContract(CompositeType composite)
        {
            if (composite == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("composite");
            }

            if (composite.BoolValue)
            {
                composite.StringValue += "Suffix";
            }

            return composite;
        }

        public string  GetCompositedata()
        {
           CompositeType ct = new CompositeType();
           return ct.StringValue;
        }
    }
}
```

web.config:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
 <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

now using svcutil I have generated proxyclass(generatedProxy.cs) and config file (serviceapp.config) and added it to a console application(client)

Client:

```
Service1Client sc = new Service1Client();
Console.WriteLine(sc.GetCompositedata());
Console.ReadKey();
```

config:

```
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                    openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                    allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                    maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
                    messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
                    useDefaultWebProxy="true">
                    <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                    <security mode="None">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
                            realm="" />
                        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://localhost:2614/Service1.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" contract="IService1"
                name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

I am not able to figure out why I am getting this exception.

Please help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is that config you display for the client part of the client app's `app.config` or `web.config`, if it's a web site / web application??

You need to include those parts in your application's config - it's not enough to have those config's in a separate file created by `svcutil.exe` - it needs to be part of your application's configuration.

Comment: it's a console application (client)

Comment: ok, working now, added one app.config in the console application and added the code (generated from svcutil) to that file, it's working now.Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The svcutil-generated configuration needs to go into your main app.config, not be included as-is.

You need to add an app.config to your project then merge the contents of the svcutil config into the configuration section.